# Get shape using tf.function()

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have this function

```
train_step_signature = [
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32)
]

@tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
def train_step(inp):
   # do stuff
```

I need to use the first dim of inp in one operation (a loop with range the shape 0 of inp), but when I try, and error pops out:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

That is obviously because of the `train_step_signature`. I've seen that it works if I drop `train_step_signature` from the args, but it takes a lot of more time to process my code. My question is, is there anyway to get this first shape without loosing the `train_step_signature` arg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a pythonic loop like `for i in range(inp.shape[0])` that is not possible because `inp.shape[0]` is `None` inside `tf.function`. Do not be afraid to use
[`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)
inside `tf.function`.

Alternatively, try to use `tf.shape(inp)[0]` instead for `inp.shape[0]`.